# Restructuring data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, calculated-columns

I have a problem with restructuring data. I have two columns, and what I want to do with these columns is stack them under their original row such that row one column one is on top of row one column two, which is on top of row two column one, which is on top of row two column two - and so on and so forth. In R form, it looks like this:

```
C1 C2
 1  2
 1  2
 1  2
```

I want it to look like this

```
C3
 1
 2
 1
 2
 1
 2
```

Comment: Search on: `[r] columns interleave`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a transpose of the dataset ie. `t(df)` which swaps the columns for rows and the output will be a `matrix` (ie. a vector with dimension attributes).  To strip off the dimensions and create the real vector, you could use `as.vector` or simply `c` (concatenate).  This can be used for creating a single column `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(C3 = c(t(df)))
```

Or another option using `mapply` (contributed by @David Arenburg).  Here, the idea is again concatenate element-by-element of columns "C1" and "C2".

```
data.frame(C3 = c(mapply(c, df$C1, df$C2)))
```

In order to check how this works, try `Map`. Here, the number of `list` elements will be equal to the `nrow` of `df`:

```
Map(`c`, df$C1, df$C2)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), C2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("C1", 
"C2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

---

And here's an illustration of the difference between a vectorized method and `*apply` family

```
n <- 1e4
df <- data.frame(C1 = rep(1, n), C2 = rep(2, n))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun = c(t(df)), David = c(mapply(c, df$C1, df$C2)))
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
# akrun   204.608   215.7795   259.9504   265.4155   275.9485   374.741   100
# David 11933.612 12245.7890 13190.8289 12399.0050 13463.8565 30267.502   100
```

Comment: It took you 15 seconds to answer, nice drow there...

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, but these kind of questions are possibly `duplicates`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, he would have gotten a hat for that last year....

Comment: Worth explaining why this works. `t(df)` swaps columns for rows. The call to `c()` turns it into a vector, concatenating the columns, ie the original rows.

Comment: @dash2 Thanks for the explanation.  Shall I add this to the post.

Comment: There is always `*apply` way that some users like for some reason `c(mapply(c, df$C1, df$C2))`

Comment: @akrun is on a roll here...

Comment: Isn't this just screaming for a `reshape2` solution as well?  Granted that's a lot harder for a newbie to grok (or maybe it's just me who invariably gets tangled up inside `melt/recast` operations :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It is possible to have `melt` solution, but the order is something that gets messed up.  I think `reshape` from `base R` could be used with some modifications in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered how this would perform:

```
matrix( data.matrix(df), ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)
```

But it was still slower than akrun's.